# Why is Ubuntu asking to install alongside Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: system-installation

I have tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (dual boot) and have come upon an odd issue. Ubuntu is asking if I want to install alongside Windows Boot Manager Rather than Windows 10. I have change the Boot Priority in the BIOS to have the hard drive listed 1st, and tried the process again, but this does not seem to resolve the issue. I have not been able to find the issue elsewhere online. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is recognizing the installed OSes by the way they are identified in the system's (hard drive) configuration.  In this case, your Windows 10 is named `Windows Boot Manager` in the configuration.

The option you are seeing is the one that will install Alongside Windows 10, since the Windows Boot Manager is the reported OS.